# Even/Odd loop counting with Modulus

Tags: c#

I am trying to create code that asks the user if want to enter in numbers. Then it asks if they want the numbers displayed as even or odds, and taking a high and low for starting and end points.

```
public void RunExercise()
    {
        int runthroughs = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Greetings, User!\nWelcome to the NumberPrinter!");
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to quit (1), or print numbers (2)?");
        int userinp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (userinp != 1)
        {
            runthroughs = runthroughs + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to print even (1) or odd (2) numbers?");
            int oddeveninp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (oddeveninp == 1 || oddeveninp == 2)
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a maximum value:");
            int maxy = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Now enter a minimum value:");
            int miny = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Highest number? {0}", maxy);
            Console.WriteLine("Lowest number? {0}", miny);
            int i;
            for (i = miny; i <= maxy; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i+ " ");
                }
                else if (i % 2 == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " ");
                }
            }
       }
   }
```

As it stands now, it prints out the entire array of numbers regardless of if the user prompted for only odd or only even.

Comment: Your loop goes as follows: If the current number in the iteration is an even number then print it. Otherwise, if the current number is odd, print it as well. So, essentially your loop prints the number when it is even, and it prints the number when it is odd. To solve your problem, you should ask yourself: **When** should it print even number, when should it not print even numbers? And in the same manner: **When** should it print odd numbers, when should it not print odd numbers...

Comment: So would a return or break statement solve that?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. Depends on how you will write your code precisely. (I assume you know what `return` and `break` do.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop should be replaced with:

```
        for (i = miny; i <= maxy; i++)
        {
            bool isEven = ( i  % 2 ) == 0;

            if ( isEven && oddeveninp == 1
              || !isEven  && oddeveninp == 2 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( i );
            }
        }
```

The main matter is that you write the number to the console if the number is even, or if the number is odd. Since any number will be odd or even, this means that you'll always print `i`.

The key point here is that you have to print the number when it is even **and** the user chose to print even numbers. Conversely, you have to print the number when it is odd **and** the user chose to print odd numbers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helps immensely! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of fact, that odd and even numbers appears alternated, so you can setup initial value for i and increment it's value by 2 each iteration.

```
if (miny % 2 != oddeveninp -1)
    miny++;
for (var i = miny; i <= maxy; i+=2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```